# In Eric Martin's Simplemodal jQuery plugin, is possible to adjust CSS on the fly?

Tags: jquery, css, simplemodal

I would like to adjust the height of the simple-container to match changing depth requirements passed on data returned from the server using $.ajax.

It seems that once the modal is fired, all CSS changes on the fly, e.g. $('#someid').css('height','500px')

Anyway to override the set CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this had been asked and answered in a different form. Here my code and now I have a dynamically resizing modal.

Added:

```
$('#simplemodal-container').css('height', 'auto');
```

as in:

```
$('#mycontainer').modal({onShow: function (dialog) {
             $('#simplemodal-container').css('height', 'auto');
        }});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please accept the answer with the checkmark to the left...it'll help the next person who has the same problem and finds this on google :)